# How to get a random maximum from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, max

I want to get a random maximum from a list using python. Say, my list is:

```
list=[0,-1,-2,0] -> index(max(list))=0
```

What I want, however, is that it randomly picks an index where the max is contained, e.g.

```
list=[0,-1,-2,0] -> index(some_func(list))=0 , index(some_func(list))=3
```

Is there a built-in function in Python that lets me do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first filter the indices containing the maximum, then use `random.choice` to pick one randomly.

```
import random

lst=[0,-1,-2,0]
max_ = max(lst)
index = random.choice([i for i in range(len(lst)) if lst[i] == max_])
```

As a sidenote, do not use `list` as variable name as it overwrites the builtin `list`.

Comment: I know, I was only making an example. Thanks for your answer. I marked it as the corrent one.

Answer (score 0):

first get the indices that contain the max values:

```
maxes = [i for i,m in enumerate(list) if m == max(list)]
```

then pick a random index from this list:

```
import random
choice = random.choice(maxes)
```

then do what you want with it..

```
print(list[choice])
```

Comment: Careful, this recomputes the maximum at every iteration, which makes the algorithmm O(n^2)

Comment: This computes the indices according to the maximum values in the list, stores them in a list, then randomly grabs one value from the indices list

Comment: could you explain your comment to me? I'm a civil eng by trade so really don't know alot about computer science/programming theory, I am curious as to how this recomputes the maximum every iteration when the list of max indices has already been predetermined?

Comment: A filter condition `if some_condition(m)` is reevaluated at every iteration. This means that your condition `if m == max(list)` is reevaluated at every iteration and in particular recomputes the maximum everytime. This is unnecessary computations since the maximum needs only to be computed once. You can have a look at my answer to see how to achieve this.

Comment: I see so just replacing max(list) with a pre-computed max would solve this?

Comment: Exactly, this way the max is computed only once